# Inside method but loop still getting expected unqualified-id error C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pybind11

I have a quick question. I have read about "expected unqualified-id" errors and how they occur when a loop is outside of a method. The issue I am having is that the loop is *inside* a method and I am still getting this? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

The error in compiler:

```
   expected unqualified-id
for(auto template : filtered) {
         ^
```

The code:

```
py::str process(string text){
    //some code...
    for(auto template : filtered) {
        //some more....
    }
    //a return
}
```

Comment: Didn't your text editor/IDE highlight `template` as a keyword?

Comment: In the question above, `template` is highlighted as a keyword.

Comment: It wasn't highlighted in Sublime, so I hadn't noticed. Thanks for pointing that out! @HolyBlackCat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`template`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates) is a reserved [keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword). It's one of the few names you are not allowed to use. Change the name of your `template` variable to any legal identifier to fix your problem. For example, try :

```
py::str process(string text){
    //some code...
    for(auto my_template : filtered) {
        //some more....
    }
    //a return
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.